# How to count the total of numbers from input in LMC

Tags: little-man-computer

I'm struggling a bit on this question. Essentially, I have to loop through a code with inputs, until the input is 0. Doing that by BRZ. And then, I have to output how many numbers that have been typed in to input. If I have typed in 1, 4, 6, 2, then the input should be 4, since there's four numbers there.

This is the code I'm currently using

```
start   INP antall
        BRZ jump
        ADD tall
        STA tall
        BRA start
jump    LDA tall
        OUT
antall  STA
        LDA
        OUT
        HLT
tall    DAT 0
antall  DAT
```

antall = total
tall = numbers
if anyone's wondering what the labels mean

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

- `INP` does not take an operand: it should be used on its own, not like `INP antall`. The user's input is loaded into the accumulator, so it doesn't need any parameter.
- Labels should be unique. You have defined two lines with the label `antall`, once for the `STA` (which can be removed) and once as the location for the end result.
- `ADD tall` adds the value in `tall` to the accumulator. But at that moment the accumulator holds the last input value, which is not something you want to include in the addition. Instead, you want to *load* the current value of `tall`, and then add 1 to it. So you need a mailbox with the value 1 in it. You could define it near the end of your code block:

  ```
  one  DAT 1
  ```
- You have both `tall` and `antall` locations, but as both uses you have for `antall` should be removed, that label and mailbox no longer have a purpose. You can just keep `tall`.
- You have a `STA` and a `LDA` without mention *where* to store/retrieve the value. Moreover it seems unnecessary code for doing what you ask about.
- There are two `OUT` instructions in your code, but reading the question you only need to output one thing: the number of inputs.

Here is the corrected code -- you can run it here:

```html
#input: 1 4 6 2 0
start   INP
        BRZ jump
        LDA tall
        ADD one
        STA tall
        BRA start
jump    LDA tall
        OUT
        HLT
one     DAT 1
tall    DAT 0


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.816/lmc.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?